# Html page cannot show properly in PyQt Qwebview

Tags: python, html, pyqt, plotly

I use PyQt4(4.11 version) and Python2.7

I would like to embedded html page in pyqt GUI by using Qwebview ,
the html were generated from plotly offline,simply contains bar chart graph like this:
[bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RlhS.png)

```
self.webView = QtWebKit.QWebView(self.centralwidget)
self..webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl('file:///D:/Anaconda/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4/my-graph.html'))
```

however, the html display nothing in QwebView, while it can show the plotly bar chart properly in windows browser

I also tried to set Url to the plotly website 
    `self.load(QtCore.QUrl('https://plot.ly/python/axes/'))`
and found out that only the plotly image cannot display properly
[text and images display well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAgZa.png)

the same problem appears when i generated html by google chart

then i tried to set the following parameters, but it still not works

```
self.webView = QtWebKit.QWebView(self.centralwidget)
s=self.webView.settings()
s.setAttribute(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
s.setAttribute(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.JavascriptEnabled, True)
s.setAttribute(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.JavascriptCanOpenWindows, True)
s.setAttribute(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.JavascriptCanAccessClipboard, True)
s.setAttribute(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.JavaEnabled, True)
s.setAttribute(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.AutoLoadImages, True)
s.setAttribute(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)
s.setAttribute(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.LocalStorageEnabled, True)        
s.setAttribute(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.SpatialNavigationEnabled, True)  
s.setAttribute(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, True)  
s.setAttribute(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls, True)
```

i have no idea now, does anyone can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Both Qt4 (which you're using with PyQt4) and QtWebKit are unmaintained.

You'll also get a webkit which is probably around 4 years old. Such an old webkit version will struggle with modern web content (apart from the obvious security and stability issues).

I'd recommend to upgrade at least to PyQt5/Qt5, and ideally from QtWebKit to [QtWebEngine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-index.html)

Comment: I have changed PyQt4 to PyQt5, QtWebKit to QtWebEngine
,although it requires python 3 and i need to modify my codes a lot, it works fine now. thanks a lot

Comment: Seeing that Python 2 also is only officially maintained for another four years, switching to Python 3 might also not be a bad idea ;)